# Linguistics needs some new leadership. Is it you?

Tags: discussion, moderation

For the past several weeks I've been on the lookout for a new pro-tem moderator for Linguistics. Unfortunately, I've had a bit of trouble finding an enthusiastic,  dedicated individual to take part in some community building. So, I am turning to the community.

**A bit about the job, and what we're looking for:**

Much like the community leaders in a small town who ensure that roads get fixed, trees get planted, and trash gets removed, each Stack Exchange site needs a team of three moderators who see to it that the site is able to continue to be a productive resource.

Ideal candidates should:

- Want the responsibility, and have at least a few hours each week to give on average
- Be consistently patient and fair in their dealings with the community
- Be knowledgeable enough about the topic to be able to judge the quality of posts, and identify cleverly crafted spam
- Be ready to lead the community to help you do your jobs. Teach people how to flag properly, encourage a culture of editors and strong reviewers
- Work directly with me and the rest of the SE community team to make sure this community is getting its needs met from us
- Understand and embrace our [theory of moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

Are you interested? Great! Leave an answer to this question to indicate your desire to be considered, and feel free to expand on what you think is a priority for the site right now. While I will consider third-party nominations, I'd rather see nominations from folks enthused enough to step in and write something down.

I aim to have someone appointed by end of the week, so don't hesitate to jump in if you're interested.

Answer (score 5):

Given that I am studying to be a *computational* linguist, I'd ideally prefer someone with more apt academic credentials than myself. However, since no one else is stepping up, I volunteer.

I already:

- Spend more than a few hours a week on Linguistics.SE.
- am fairly knowledgeable of the topic -- some aspects of the topic, at any rate.
- flag, and vote up, down, and to close fairly actively.

Comment: thank you for stepping up. I'll be sending you a message soon to handle some next steps.