# Important Notice: Linguistics SE needs new leadership

Tags: discussion, moderation

Linguistics Stack Exchange is a small site, but plays host to a strong community of experts.

That's why it’s strange that [I can't find anyone to step up as a new pro-tem moderator](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/526/linguistics-needs-some-new-leadership-is-it-you). Two and a half weeks ago, I made a meta post asking for someone to volunteer to help moderate this site. No one has come forward.

I'm bringing this to everyone's attention here, on the main site, because there appears to be very little focus on meta. I **need** to find *someone* willing to help the [existing team](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) lead and support Linguistics SE. Otherwise I will be forced to escalate the situation.

Comment: I have really come to appreciate this forum, mainly because there are number of quite knowledgable people here. I have been promoting the forum by drawing my colleagues attention to the site. I have considered the moderator role myself, but have decided that taking on such a responsibility in my current life situation is not wise. It should be known, however, that while I may disagree on occasion with the decisions of a moderator, their efforts and contributions are very beneficial to the site.

Comment: **To everyone**: Moderating a website is not just having a diamond next to your nickname. It's also voting to close a question, flagging content, voting, etc. All of this small actions help the community shape itself. Moderators are supposed to be exception handlers, but more than often we are the *only ones* that close questions. I often see comments that say "this is off topic" but no close votes. Not to mention other things, but this one is really important. If you see a bad question, vote to close. If you see spam/problems, flag.

Comment: Being forced to escalate the situation sounds ominous! :-) If no one else feels up to it, I volunteer.

Comment: @prash If you feel like nominating yourself, you can write an answer below this question. I'll migrate it to Meta when everything is done. Maybe write a bit about you, especially  moderator-related stuff that you think might be relevant.

Comment: @Alenanno: I posted my answer on meta already.

Comment: Very strange to have a meta question on the main site. I don't know whether to vote it as off topic or not. We surely have no need beyond this one question for a "moderation" tag. I take this as evidence of desperate times \-:

Comment: @hippietrail The problem with current SE design is that links to Meta are too deeply hidden behind the menu in the top bar. This effectively **eliminates new users from awareness about Meta** and participation in it. Instead of "Hot Network questions" in the right bar, there could be an excerpt of N most recent Meta questions (not only "featured" ones).

Comment: @bytebuster: There is something like that. There's the "Community Bulletin" above "Hot Network Questions" and you can even add a "featured article" tag to a meta question to get it some more attention on the front page. I don't know the details but they should be around on meta.SO or wherever mods get their moderating info from (-:

Comment: @bytebuster I agree that we could (and should) do better at promoting meta. However, many meta sites (including the one here) have grown quiet long before the meta link was removed from the top bar. This isn't just a "new users aren't aware" problem.

Comment: @AnnaLear Even so, putting the link to Meta in an even more hidden position, inside a drop-down menu that is, certainly doesn't help to make it more known to new users.